# How Can I Set Up A Desktop Shared folder that's only accessible to me on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I have used the UI to create a file share called (imaginatively) 'Shared' and initially tried to set it up so only my account would have access.

When I try to connect to the share via Nautilus on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop the connection fails.

I have looked at and tweaked the default smb.conf ever so slightly to add the following rather than the default workgroup...

```
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
workgroup = MINISTRY
server min protocol = NT1
```

Am trying to log in with...

**Connect As:** Registered User

**Username:** {me on my desktop}

**Domain:** MINISTRY

**Password:** {me on my desktops password}

This doesn't seem to work - I tried also switching the domain entry for 'stu-art.local' (the desktop name) and no dice there either.

I managed to connect eventually by enabling guest access on my desktop and selecting

**Connect As:** Anonymous

on the laptop instead but, obviously this isn't ideal.

My username and password are the same on the laptop and the desktop - I am wondering if that is creating some weird confusion somewhere or if my username needs to be prefixed like an AD name would be in Windows world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two passwords for a given user on your samba server: The one you use to log into the server machine locally and the one you use to connect to the samba server and its share across the network.

If your login username is keith you would need to add that user to the samba password database to enable its samba password. You do that with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a keith
```

Comment: Of course - I remember doing this years back now when I had a linux domain server!